# How to make a draggable object open new page on collision?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm super new to HTML/CSS/JS and have a bit of a funny question. I codes that I'm basically trying to combine and I'm not sure what's the smartest way of doing it, or how to break down the elements of the code in a way that I know what I'm doing.

I would like to know how to create a script that allows you to move elements around a page smoothly, and then has an area that detects which image is in that area and changes the webpage based on this.

Basically, I have a webpage where the outcome I would like is that I have two images - one of a console and one of a CD. When a user drags the CD into the console, the webpage updates to whatever game has been dragged into the console image area.

I've basically managed to get these elements working separately - a CD that when dragged into the area changes the webpage (based on this code: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop2), and a CD that drags smoothly.

This is my example page: https://electrazzz.neocities.org/projects

How do I rearrange this so that it works as intended? So sorry if this is a silly question, completely new to JS and would appreciate the help.

And is there also a way to make the script detect which image is in the box? So, if I had multiple CD's, is there a way of making these go to specific unique pages based on the individual CD?

```js
function startDrag(e) {
  // determine event object
  if (!e) {
    var e = window.event;
  }

  // IE uses srcElement, others use target
  var targ = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;

  if (targ.className != 'dragme') {return};
  // calculate event X, Y coordinates
    offsetX = e.clientX;
    offsetY = e.clientY;

  // assign default values for top and left properties
  if(!targ.style.left) { targ.style.left='0px'};
  if (!targ.style.top) { targ.style.top='0px'};

  // calculate integer values for top and left 
  // properties
  coordX = parseInt(targ.style.left);
  coordY = parseInt(targ.style.top);
  drag = true;

  // move div element
  document.onmousemove=dragDiv;
}

function dragDiv(e) {
  if (!drag) {return};
  if (!e) { var e= window.event};
  var targ=e.target?e.target:e.srcElement;
  // move div element
  targ.style.left=coordX+e.clientX-offsetX+'px';
  targ.style.top=coordY+e.clientY-offsetY+'px';
  return false;
}

function stopDrag() {
  drag=false;
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.onmousedown = startDrag;
  document.onmouseup = stopDrag;
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  var myWindow = window.open("JourneyThroughLove.html", "_self");
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 800px;
  height: 520px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

.dragme {
  position:relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  cursor: move;
}

#draggable {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <p>
    Drag the disc into the drive
  </p>

  <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="https://electrazzz.neocities.org/Images/Graphics/2D/CD/PS2_Original.png" width="800" height="640" />
  </div>

  <br>

  <img
    id="drag1"
    src="https://electrazzz.neocities.org/Images/Graphics/2D/CD/LoveTime_Disc.png"
    draggable="true"
    ondragstart="drag(event)" 
    width="400"
    height="400"
  />
  <img
    src="https://electrazzz.neocities.org/Images/Graphics/2D/CD/LoveTime_Disc.png"
    alt="drag-and-drop image script" 
    title="drag-and-drop image script"
    class="dragme"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might not fully answer your question, but regarding detecting collision between the CD being dragged into the PS2 Image, you could try out the following to detect overlapping element:

```js
function isOverlapping(elem1, elem2) {
    const rect1 = elem1.getBoundingClientRect()
    const rect2 = elem2.getBoundingClientRect()
    return !(rect1.right < rect2.left ||
        rect1.left > rect2.right ||
        rect1.bottom < rect2.top ||
        rect1.top > rect2.bottom)
}
```

and add the following to your `stopDrag()` function to check for overlapping CD image(s) element and ps2 image:

```js
function stopDrag() {
    drag = false;
    const cdImages = document.getElementsByClassName("dragme")
    const ps2Div = document.getElementById("div1")
    for (let cdImage of cdImages) {
        if (isOverlapping(cdImage, ps2Div)) {
            var myWindow = window.open("JourneyThroughLove.html", "_self");
        }
    }

}
```

What the above does is, after you stop dragging it will check if any of your CD images elements is overlapping the PS2 image.

As for your second question, there are multiple ways to detect which image is dragged into the ps2 image. One method is to check the name of the CD image being dragged. You'd have to add a name property to the element to do this.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        Test
    </title>

    <style>
        #div1 {
            width: 800px;
            height: 520px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
        }

        .dragme {
            position: relative;
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            cursor: move;
        }

        #draggable {
            background-color: #ccc;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div align="center">
        <p>
            Drag the disc into the drive
        </p>

        <div id="div1"><img src="./PS2_Original.png" width="800" height="640">
        </div>

        <br>

        <img src="./LoveTime_Disc.png" name="JourneyThroughLove" alt="drag-and-drop image script"
            title="drag-and-drop image script" class="dragme">

        <img src="./LoveTime_Disc.png" name="ThroughLove" alt="drag-and-drop image script"
            title="drag-and-drop image script" class="dragme">

    </div>

    <script>
        function startDrag(e) {
            // determine event object
            if (!e) {
                var e = window.event;
            }

            // IE uses srcElement, others use target
            var targ = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;

            if (targ.className != 'dragme') { return };
            // calculate event X, Y coordinates
            offsetX = e.clientX;
            offsetY = e.clientY;

            // assign default values for top and left properties
            if (!targ.style.left) { targ.style.left = '0px' };
            if (!targ.style.top) { targ.style.top = '0px' };

            // calculate integer values for top and left 
            // properties
            coordX = parseInt(targ.style.left);
            coordY = parseInt(targ.style.top);
            drag = true;

            // move div element
            document.onmousemove = dragDiv;

        }
        function dragDiv(e) {
            if (!drag) { return };
            if (!e) { var e = window.event };
            var targ = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;
            // move div element
            targ.style.left = coordX + e.clientX - offsetX + 'px';
            targ.style.top = coordY + e.clientY - offsetY + 'px';
            return false;
        }
        function stopDrag() {
            drag = false;
            const cdImages = document.getElementsByClassName("dragme")
            const ps2Div = document.getElementById("div1")
            for (let cdImage of cdImages) {
                if (isOverlapping(cdImage, ps2Div)) {
                    var myWindow = window.open(`${cdImage.name}.html`, "_self");
                }
            }

        }
        window.onload = function () {
            document.onmousedown = startDrag;
            document.onmouseup = stopDrag;
        }

        function isOverlapping(elem1, elem2) {
            const rect1 = elem1.getBoundingClientRect()
            const rect2 = elem2.getBoundingClientRect()
            return !(rect1.right < rect2.left ||
                rect1.left > rect2.right ||
                rect1.bottom < rect2.top ||
                rect1.top > rect2.bottom)
        }
    </script>



</body>

</html>
```